# can't load docker image from another machine

Tags: docker

i have builded a docker images (with size 23gb) and save it on my machine, then i have copied the tar file to an other machine and i have tried to load the image with:

**`docker load -i filename.tar`**
but i got this error:

```
invalid diffID for layer 5: expected "sha256:2640e1c5fdaa83b3db112ad2d0860f0a3a99ff1b07dd2424ae053fcdd1e853d6", got "sha256:e2317926e660d99ff13a7cbfd755d75cf600ee8b38502c288cb015f71d5a386a"
```

the docker engine is the same on the both machines.

Comment: Currently not sure which one is better but try both `docker export` & `docker save`. I had similar problem. And don't forget to remove old image on target server

Comment: How have you exported the docker image?

Comment: i have already tried to export the image and import it in the other machine, it was safely imported. NB: My image contains oracleDB so when i imported the image in the other machine i can't call sqlplus cammand the the oracle_home and oracle_sid where removed .. 
my image size is 23gb when i exported it the tar file was 12gb and when i saved it it was about 22gb

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by:

1. resaveing the docker images
2. recopy it in the second machine and doing the docker load